# What is this weed, and how to remove it?

Tags: identification, weed-control, weeds

Does anyone know what this is? and how I can remove it from my yard without hurting my yard?

This is in Houston Texas, it is found just through-out my yard. It is full sunlight pretty much all day, and it popped up about two weeks ago and it seems to love the rain we have been having lately.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That my friend is a dandelion.

You can leave it and mow it and it won't hurt anything. Or you can get a gardening fork and pull them out one at a time, but make sure you get the tap root.

They are a good first pollen source for bees, they flower even before maple trees do.

It could also be chicory known as "Texas dandelion" it also happens to be in the dandelion tribe as well and not just a lookalike.

Comment: Very unlike what I call a dandelion in habit. But obviously in the Asteraceae  family, probably in a related genus.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't look like a dandelion.

Comment: Perhaps a dandelion with a phosphate deficiency giving it a reddish color.